# Trino: Can not create schemas when the s3 endpoint links to folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, presto, minio, trino

I am currently building a project with trino for testing purposes using docker compose. I have created a catalog which points to the following s3 endpoint: `hive.s3.endpoint=http://minio:9000/sample-lakehouse/raw/`  However I can not create any schema, f.e like this: `create schema iceberg_raw.insurance_data with (LOCATION = 's3://sample-lakehouse/raw/insurance_data');`  If I leave the s3.endpoint to just `hive.s3.endpoint=http://minio:9000`  Everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is because `http://minio:9000` is the Endpoint where commands are sent. The remaining portions are _not_ part of the Endpoint.

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can still create catalogs which point to "folders" within my minio storage ?